# What kind of IC is this, and how can I erase its memory to reuse it?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, memory, reuse

I have a PCB with an IC on it.

All I want is to erase its memory so that I can reuse the chip.

Any help with what sort of chip is this, or how I can erase the memory, would be very helpful.

[image: PCB front image]

[image: PCB rear image]

Comment: If you don't know what sort of chip it is, how do you know you want to reuse it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a TI MSP430G2402.

While in theory possible to connect it to PC with a MSP430 programmer/debugger, most likely the chip has read out lock bits turned on and disabled the programming interface to prevent re-using that board (e.g. if it is a board from an ink cartridge of some sort).

A new chip costs 2-3 dollars/euros if bought one at a time so given that you need the programming interface anyway just buy a new chip.

Comment: Thanks for the info. you are exactly bang on that this chip is from ink cartridge. Here its not easily available and hence very expensive (15-20$ approx) and I use these cartridges in large numbers which increases cost drastically.

Comment: One more question, would buying the new chip and merely replacing will work? Or is any programming would be required?

Comment: Obviously an empty chip with no program does nothing so the chips need to be flashed with software that makes them work.

Comment: @user9552213 It's not a "chip" (meaningless term), it's a microcontroller. It needs to be programmed by the manufacturer of the product. It will have copy cat protection against hacking the flash. While you will be able to mass erase all of the memory over JTAG, you'll only end up with a blank microcontroller which is just a dead piece of silicon that does absolutely nothing. An engineer could use it for other purposes from there on, but not for the intended use inside the ink cartridge.

Answer (score 6):

This one is relatively easy to find.

First of all that logo looks a lot like Texas (Instruments).

A quick web search for the first line "G2402" yields the [MSP430 family](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430G2402) of microcontrollers, which comes in a matching 14-lead package.

From here on, read the datasheet and figure out which pins are connected.

Answer (score 3):

As for the identification: it is a Texas Instruments MSP430G2402IPW14 mixed-signal microcontroller, according to the markings list in its [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2402.pdf).

How to "erase its memory" I don't know, but that information is probably in the datasheet somewhere. A programmer will be required, or at least convenient.